# Count number of rows that contain a string in table view always returns 1

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

My app dynamically adds table view rows that receive a pass/fail result displayed as the cell string (in addition to a description).  Im trying to count the amount of cells that receive a fail result in the text.  My problem is that my `NSLog(@"Counted times: %i", times);` always returns 1 rather than adding them up.

```
 cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Appliance %@:  %@", ((Circuit *)[self.circuits objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]).circuitReference,((Circuit *)[self.circuits objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]).rcdTestButton];
    if(cell.textLabel.text && [cell.textLabel.text rangeOfString:@"Fail"].location != NSNotFound){
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];

        NSString *string = @"str";
        int times = [[string componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"] count];

        NSLog(@"Counted times: %i", times);

    }
```

UPDATED CODE

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
   NSString *string = @"str";
   int times = [[string componentsSeparatedByString:@"str"] count];


static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
if (indexPath.section == 0) {
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Summary of appliance testing";
} else {
    //Appliance label text
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Appliance %@:  %@", ((Circuit *)[self.circuits objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]).circuitReference,((Circuit *)[self.circuits objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]).rcdTestButton];
    if(cell.textLabel.text && [cell.textLabel.text rangeOfString:@"Fail"].location != NSNotFound){
        cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];

        NSLog(@"Counted times: %i", times);

     }

        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@""];
}
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

return cell;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
NSString *string = @"str";
int times = [[string componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"] count];
```

Why would you expect this to ever return anything other than 1?

If you want to count the number of rows that meet some criteria, you need to loop through your data (not the cells), and check each value in your data.

Comment: There is a reason why im checking the cells rather than data on this. Point taken on the str but with typo fixed it returns 2 all the time

Comment: And what is the reason for looking at the cells and not the data? It's extremely inefficient to look at every cell. What if there are hundreds of rows? You needlessly create all of those cells just to look at text you already have in your data model. And without seeing your updated code, there is no way to help you further with the problem.

Comment: The data modal is already passing the data to the cell row to fill out its result , the cells are already created and data is passed to fill out the cell with info, looking at the cell string makes no difference to efficiency as the data already is passed there regardless of if im reading from it.

Comment: Assuming you are using standard cell reuse, there are only enough cells to fill the screen. So not every cell exists at once. If you have far more rows than fit on the screen at once, you are needlessly creating cells that don't need to be created just so you can extract strings built from data that you already have in the data source. Cells are for display. Your data source has the actual data. That's what it is for. Don't use the views to process data. Use the data to process the data.

Comment: Ah right thats makes sense re the efficiency, thanks for the tip, will re think this

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are initializing the counter inside the loop, which constantly resets it. Declare the variable before the loop, then simply iterate it inside the loop.

Comment: I think you mean "increment", not "iterate".

Comment: Thanks for reply but that makes no difference although I have corrected what you pointed out.

Comment: Oops, yes. Increment is what I meant.